# Extracting ID string from GDataEntry

Tags: python, gdata, gdata-api

I am playing around with Google's gdata API in python. More specificalyl, I am using the YouTube API, but I do not believe it will be relevant to this question.

I now have an object which is a subclass of GDataEntry and I am trying to get its id.

```
print entry.id
```

this fails as it cannot convert and Id object to a string. So I try:

```
print str(entry.id)
```

which serializes it to an XML string. What I really want is the textual content of the ID. I have been looking through the docs, and I was unable to find it so far. I am convinced this is really easy to do, but I cannot find the right method to get the text content of the Id object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure, that `entry.id` is of the type `atom.Id` which provides a `ToString` method and a `text` accessor. See the [documentation here](http://static.whit537.org/2007/gdata-python/1.0/gdata.atom.Id-class.html).

So you'd like to write:

```
print entry.id.text
```